# How do I handle undocumented Income from consulting to a foreign firm

Tags: united-states, income, form-1099, form-w-2

I occasionally do some consulting support (in the US) to a foreign firm. They don't send me any 1099 or W4 documenting the income, though they do a wire transfer to my account. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a 1099 to report income.  You just report it.  The IRS doesn't care one bit if your Schedule C income exceeds your 1099s.

Comment: And it does care quite a lot if you have unreported incoming wire transfers, especially if those come up in an audit. So yes, report on Schedule C just like any other income.